# Is is possible to withdraw ETH without payable?

Tags: solidity, payable

I'm practicing [How to Build a Staking Dapp](https://docs.alchemy.com/docs/how-to-build-a-staking-dapp) example in Alchemy.
In Staker.sol, there's a `withdraw` function which hasn't a payable keyword. But it does work. Isn't it necessary to use 'payable' when transferring eth?

```js
function withdraw() public withdrawlDeadlineReached(true) claimDeadlineReached(false) notCompleted {
    require(balances[msg.sender] > 0 , "You have no balance to withdraw!");
    uint256 individualBalance = balances[msg.sender];
    uint256 indBalanceReward = individualBalance + ((block.timestamp - depositTimestamps[msg.sender]) * rewardRatePerBlock);
    balances[msg.sender] = 0;

    (bool sent, bytes memory data) = msg.sender.call{value: indBalanceReward}("");
    require(sent, "RIP, withdrawl failed :( ");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `payable` modifier when a function you write intends to receive ether (e.g. `deposit()`, `receive()`, `fallback()`...etc). Your withdraw function is not intended to receive ether, so no `payable` modifier is necessary. And no, it isn't necessary to use `payable` when transferring ether.

See: [payable() function In solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/20874/payable-function-in-solidity)

Answer (score 1):

you should convert msg.sender to address payable:

take a look at the [doc](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.14/080-breaking-changes.html)

> The global variables tx.origin and msg.sender have the type address instead of address payable. One can convert them into address payable by using an explicit conversion, i.e., payable(tx.origin) or **payable(msg.sender)**.

```
(bool sent, bytes memory data) = payable(msg.sender).call{value: indBalanceReward}("");
```

Answer (score 0):

To further clear your understanding of this a similar question like this was asked [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/135821/difference-between-address-payable-and-payableaddress). It explain the difference between the two.